# "The only witness is a prostitute!" What do you call this type of rhetoric in English?

Tags: terminology, rhetoric, figures-of-speech

The defense attorney:

> “…and finally, ladies and gentlemen of the jury, my client can never
>   be considered legally guilty unless the prosecutor can prove it beyond
>   a reasonable doubt. And, consider this seriously: the only putative
>   witness is a prostitute.”

What do we call this type of rhetoric or fallacy in English?

Comment: This is a legal question, not a linguistic one.

Comment: A legal question asks for a legal conclusion.  The OP is asking about language and logic.

Comment: @Theresa I agree that it is not a legal question; but I'm dubious about calling it a language question. Logic and for the most part rhetoric are not language-specific; This is not a question about English; exactly the same answer would be called for if the passage in question were in French or Urdu or Arabic.

Comment: OP is on an English site, asking what English terms are apt.

Comment: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com is a better fit, we take questions like that all the time over there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about logic not about English.

Comment: If I want to know what something is called in English, it's a language question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is both a rhetorical strategy and a fallacy.

The rhetorical strategy is *distraction*, to bring the jury's attention off-task.

For fallacies, *Red Herring* fits, since the relation of prostitution to her propensity for truth-telling is not obvious.

It is also the fallacy of *ad hominem* attack on the witness, that is, an attack on her as a person rather than evidence contrary to her testimony.

It may also be an example of the fallacy *appeal to emotion*.

The Nizkor Project gives many good examples of logical fallacies: [Nizkor, Fallacies](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/red-herring.html)

The question is not a legal question, since it is not asking for a legal conclusion. It is a question concerning language and logic.

Comment: +1 -If I'm not mistaken, it is a *red herring*: subset *ad hominem*: subset *poisoning the well*.

Comment: Prostitution implies, at best, a lack of respect for the law, which self evidently makes her sworn evidence less believable.  You can't call an argument fallacious because you dislike it.

Comment: @TimLymington Legality depends on the jurisdiction, but you're correct in the concept. A witness' background or history may lower the "reliability" of his/her testimony. E.g., if the defence can show that the prosecution has a history of lying or false accusation, they may be able to discredit the claims in the eyes of the jury. Whether or not this applies to this particular instance is a separate matter, and probably impossible to judge without more context.

Comment: @Unsigned: Entirely agree, but you are overlooking the title of this site. An argument that may or may not be good in this context cannot be called (without other reason) fallacious.

Comment: @TimLymington Agreed, fair point.

Comment: Impeaching credibility--This term is used to describe questions addressed to a witness during cross-examination and bearing on that witness's lack of credibility. This statement is a summation to the jury relating to a prior witness's testimony.